# How to ensure referential integrity at circular relationship tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have schema like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6mwP.png)

In this database,

- chapter has many roles
- chapter has many visitors
- visitor belongs to a role

My question is, how to ensure `the visitor and its role should have same chapter_id`

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: How is that "circular"? FKs have a direction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need chapter_id in visitor table. It is redundant because from the role_id, you an tell the chapter the visitor belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

Notes

```
[p x]   = predicate  x
(c x.y) = constraint x.y

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key

All attributes (columns) NOT NULL
```

---

**[p 1]** Role `ROLE_ID` exists.

*(c 1.1) Role is identified by `ROLE_ID`*.

```
role {ROLE_ID}  -- p 1
  PK {ROLE_ID}  -- c 1.1
```

**[p 2]** Person `PERSON_ID` exists.

*(c 2.1) Person is identified by `PERSON_ID`*.

```
person {PERSON_ID} -- p 2
    PK {PERSON_ID} -- c 2.1
```

**[p 3]** Chapter `CHAPTER_ID` exists.

*(c 3.1) Chapter is identified by `CHAPTER_ID`*.

```
chapter {CHAPTER_ID}  -- p 3
     PK {CHAPTER_ID}  -- c 3.1
```

**[p 4]**  Person `PERSON_ID` has role `ROLE_ID`.

*(c 4.1) For each person, that person may have more than one role;

 for each role, that role may belong to more than one person.*

*(c 4.2) If a person has a role, than that person must exist*.

*(c 4.3) If a person has a role, than that role must exist*.

```
person_role {PERSON_ID, ROLE_ID}    -- p 4
         PK {PERSON_ID, ROLE_ID}    -- c 4.1

        FK1 {PERSON_ID} REFERENCES
     person {PERSON_ID}             -- c 4.2

        FK2 {ROLE_ID} REFERENCES
       role {ROLE_ID}               -- c 4.3
```

**[p 5]**  Chapter `CHAPTER_ID` has role `ROLE_ID`.

*(c 5.1) For each chapter, that chapter may have more than one role; for each role, that role may belong to more than one chapter.*

*(c 5.2) If a chapter has a role, than that chapter must exist*.

*(c 5.3) If a chapter has a role, than that role must exist*.

```
chapter_role {CHAPTER_ID, ROLE_ID}      -- p 5
          PK {CHAPTER_ID, ROLE_ID}      -- c 5.1

         FK1 {CHAPTER_ID} REFERENCES
     chapter {CHAPTER_ID}               -- c 5.2

         FK2 {ROLE_ID} REFERENCES
        role {ROLE_ID}                  -- c 5.3
```

**[p 6]** Person `PERSON_ID` with role `ROLE_ID` visited chapter `CHAPTER_ID` having role `ROLE_ID` -- as some point in time.

*(c 6.1) For each person, that person may have visited more than one chapter, at some point in time. For each chapter, that chapter may have been visited by more than one person, at some point in time.*

*(c 6.2) If a person visited a chapter having a role, then that person must have that role.*

*(c 6.3) If a person having a role visited a chapter, then that chapter must have that role.*

```
visit {PERSON_ID, CHAPTER_ID, ROLE_ID}          -- p 6
   PK {PERSON_ID, CHAPTER_ID}                   -- c 6.1

        FK1 {PERSON_ID, ROLE_ID} REFERENCES
person_role {PERSON_ID, ROLE_ID}                -- c 6.2

         FK2 {CHAPTER_ID, ROLE_ID} REFERENCES
chapter_role {CHAPTER_ID, ROLE_ID}              -- c 6.3
```